# Opening one modal for many posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of posts and on every posts I can open a modal. The problem is I want code for a single modal and to use dynamic the modal.

Here is my actual code: https://jsfiddle.net/wrucjszv/

In future I will fetch posts with ajax will be an array, and I don't want to create a modal for each post. I want to use a single modal but to have the content from inside dynamic. In my case I have the button with the id

```
#myBtn
```

with the content "Some text in the Modal..". In the second maybe I will have "I'm not so good at javascript" and the list can goes on. I want to have the modal dynamic with content from inside. What can I do?

**EDIT**:

https://jsfiddle.net/wrucjszv/4/

here you can see more exactly why I want that. In future I will have a lot of posts, and I don't have to load a ton of modals. I want a single modle and I want to have the posibility to edit each post in a modal, I need to have this dynamic. In placeholder I need to have the title and description of the post, and I need to submit the edit modal with the ID of the post.

Comment: Please don't use the same id for multiple elements. Even in an example. You can listen to class instead, which can be shared

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is update the content just before you show the modal, everything else can remain the same. See a fork of your jsFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hvpvfc67/

All I did was add an additional div inside your modal content element so we can get access to the text.

```
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-text">
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then I get a reference to the new div:

```
var modalContent = document.querySelector('.modal-text');
```

And finally update the HTML inside that div in your click handler:

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modalContent.innerHTML = "The text has changed!";
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```